# Python program to extract text from a text file?

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7, pyscripter

I have a text file which I obtained from converting a .srt file. The content is as follows:

```
1
0:0:1,65 --> 0:0:7,85
Hello, my name is Gareth, and in this
video, I'm going to talk about list comprehensions


2
0:0:7,85 --> 0:0:9,749
in Python.
```

I want only the words present the text file such that the output is a new textfile op.txt, with the output represented as:

```
Hello
my
name 
is
Gareth
and
```

and so on.

This is the program I'm working on:

```
import os, re
f= open("D:\captionsfile.txt",'r')
k=f.read()
g=str(k)
f.close()
w=re.search('[a-z][A-Z]\s',g)
fil=open('D:\op.txt','w+')
fil.append(w)
fil.close()
```

But the output I get for this program is:

```
None
None
None
```

Comment: Your regex is wrong. I think you need a bit more practice at it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If we assume `m` is a word and short for `am` and that `in.txt` is your textfile, you can use

```
import re

with open('in.txt') as intxt:
    data = intxt.read()

x = re.findall('[aA-zZ]+', data)
print(x)
```

which will produce

```
['Hello', 'my', 'name', 'is', 'Gareth', 'and', 'in', 'this', 'video', 'I', 'm', 'going', 'to', 'talk', 'about', 'list', 'comprehensions', 'in', 'Python']
```

You can now write `x` to a new file with:

```
with open('out.txt', 'w') as outtxt:
    outtxt.write('\n'.join(x))
```

To get

```
I'm
```

instead of

```
I
m
```

you can use `re.findall('[aA-zZ\']+')`

Comment: when did m become a word?

Comment: @Padraic Cunningham I am not sure whether "I'm" is A word or should be treated as two words, namely "I" and "am" where "m" in "I'm" is short for "am".

Comment: Doesn't your regex has to be `'[a-zA-Z]+'`?

Comment: Ok, it definitely has to be `'[a-zA-Z]+'`. If you use `'[aA-zZ\']+'` you have all ascii characters from A to z, which means that words like `'hell[]o'` would also be matched, because '[' and ']' are between 'A' and 'z' (if you have a look at the ascii table).

Answer (score 1):

```
with open("out.txt","a") as f1:
    with open("b.txt")  as f:
        for line in f:
            if not line[0].isdigit():
                for word in line.split():
                    f1.write(re.sub(r'[,.!]', "", word)) # replace any punctuation you don't want
                    f1.write("\n")
```